# Find the parametric equation of a circular helix in space with central axis the $z$-axis and radius $5$.

Tags: calculus

Find the parametric equation of a circular helix in space with central axis the $z$-axis and radius $5$.

$$
x=5\cos(t)\\
y=5\sin(t)\\
z=bt
$$  where the distance between two loops of the helix is $2\pi b$.
Can I find the value of $b$ with the information given?

Comment: No need to find the value of b, paramedic equation can have the b term in it.

Comment: I was mistaken that b can b found, b is a parameter on its own and can have any value.

Comment: So if I wish I can make $b=1$?

Comment: Leave b as b, you don't need a specific value for it.

Comment: If you are going to be so general as to leave $b$ as a parameter, you might want to also introduce a phase shift parameter into your trig functions. You could go into full generality, or you could specify one specific curve. Right now what you have is fine, but it's in the middle.